# Append a text string to WooCommerce product title

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, string-concatenation

```
<div class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><? wc_get_template('single-product/title.php');?>
```

Im trying to make this string say: "Product Name More Info"

I can get the Product Name part fine, but how do i concatenate the 'more info' to this code to make it output correctly? Every echo attempt i try breaks my site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look to the template `single-product/title.php` code you have essentially just this:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

The WordPress function `the_title()` echoes the product title, so you can't use echo again if you want to append "More Info" to the title. You will use this line instead:

```
<div class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><? the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', ' More Info</h1>' ); ?>
```

or in a more cleaner way.

```
<div class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><? the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', ' '. __("More Info") . '</h1>' ); ?>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: how do i put a different class on this line that allows me to style it in this div only? Ive tried everything but it seems like it wants to change the title text all over my site and i don't want that. I need it changed only in this very specific area.

I've tried <div class="newClass">, I've tried <h1 class="product_title entry-title newClass"> amongst a couple other attempts and it seems i just can't get this thing to budge and bend to my will.

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to concatinate product name title with a string, then you can use the `woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title` hook.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
function change_product_title() {
    $additional_text = ' More info';
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() .$additional_text.'</h2>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','change_product_title');
```

Or if you want to change the title of product in single product page then,

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );

function woocommerce_template_single_title_custom(){
    $additional_text = ' More Info';
    the_title( '<h3 class="product_title entry-title">', $additional_text.'</h3>' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title_custom', 5);
```

Where the syntax for `the_title` function is

```
the_title( $before, $after, $echo );
```

Comment: is this the simplest way? isn't there a way to add on the existing code without having to go back into my functions.php to make the edit?

Comment: I think it's better to add code to functions.php without making change in theme or plugin

Comment: If you need to change existing code then you may have to go with the answer of @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 1):

A great question and it has taken me several days and lots of Stack Overflowing to find a solution that worked for me.

Using @melvin 's answer (the second solution), I made some changes to avoid duplication of the title and $additional_text.  I also included a double line break and applied a class.

Replace OUR REVIEW OF with your preferred text.  The double 'break' is purely for styling and can be removed if required.

This is my solution (added to child theme - functions.php), tested and working on WooCommerce v.5.51:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );

function woocommerce_template_single_title_custom(){
    $additional_text = ' OUR REVIEW OF '."<br><br>";
   
echo "<span style='font-size: 30px; color: #00a4cc; vertical-align: top;'>".$additional_text."</span>";
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title_custom', 5);
```